# Menu mudando conforme a resolução

Tags: html, css

O menu do meu website muda conforme a resolução de um dispositivo, isso deixa ele meio desconfigurado.

Há como deixar esse menu "fixado" em qualquer resolução?

Normal (como eu quero que fique):
[image: Normal]

Em outra resolução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BurnSec</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav">
    <li id="settings">
        <a href="https://github.com/burnsecurity"><img src="https://designmodo.com/demo/dropdown-menu-search/settings.png" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="options">
        <a href="#">Serviços</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">PenTest</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="paginas/ferramentas.html">Ferramentas</a>
    </li>
<li class="options borda-direita">
  <a href="#">Cursos</a>
  <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="paginas/certificados.html">Premium</a></li>
      <li><a href="paginas/gratuitos.html">Gratuitos</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
    <li id="search">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search"/>
            <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button"></a>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li class="options">
        <a href="#">Tutoriais</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="paginas/hacking.html">Hacking</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/programacao.html">Programação</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/pentest.html">PenTest</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/outros.html">Outros</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="paginas/contato.html">Contato</a>
    <li class="borda-direita">
        <a href="paginas/sobre.html">Sobre</a>
    </li>
</ul> 
<center><h1>BurnSec</h1></center>
<script src="prefixfree-1.0.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<script src="js/particles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
 body {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  background-image:url('index1.jpg');
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:#000;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav {
    background: black;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.nav li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #0000CD;
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #0000CD;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 205, 0.5);
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}

#settings a {
    padding: 18px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
#search {
    width: 357px;
    margin: 4px;
}
#search_text{
    width: 297px;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 52px;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background: #191919;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color: white;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: white;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: white;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color: white;
}
#search_text:focus {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#search_button {
    border: 0 none;
    background: #191919 url(https://designmodo.com/demo/dropdown-menu-search/search.png) center no-repeat;
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.options a{
    border-left: 0 none;
}
.options>a {
    background-image: url(triangle.png);
    background-position: 85% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 42px;
}
.subnav {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    background: #232323;
}
.subnav li {
    float: none;
}
.subnav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
}
.options:hover .subnav {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

h1{
    color: #E6E6FA;
    font-size:45px;
    font-family: Awesome;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px;
}
h2{
    color:white;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px;
}

.borda-direita{
   border-right: 1px solid #0000CD;
}
```

Comment: Vc quer que o menu ocupe a largura toda da tela?

Comment: Isso, pois conforme maior a tela, mais ele estica ao lado direito e fica muito estranho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque `display: flex;` na `.nav` para usá-la como flexbox e adicione as propriedades `flex-grow: 1;` e `text-align: center;` nas `.nav li` para distribuir as `li` dentro de toda a largura do menu e centralizar o texto.

No `#search_text` coloque `width: calc(100% - 60px);` para deixar responsivo o campo de busca (os `60px` descontados do `100%` é a largura do botão).

Desta forma o menu irá ocupar toda a largura da tela e os itens distribuídos uniformemente.

**Veja:**

Execute em tela cheia.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
 body {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  background-image:url('index1.jpg');
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:#000;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav {
    background: black;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #0000CD;
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #0000CD;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 205, 0.5);
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}

#settings a {
    padding: 18px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
#search {
    width: 357px;
    margin: 4px;
}
#search_text{
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 52px;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background: #191919;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color: white;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: white;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: white;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color: white;
}
#search_text:focus {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#search_button {
    border: 0 none;
    background: #191919 url(https://designmodo.com/demo/dropdown-menu-search/search.png) center no-repeat;
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.options a{
    border-left: 0 none;
}
.options>a {
    background-image: url(triangle.png);
    background-position: 85% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 42px;
}
.subnav {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    background: #232323;
}
.subnav li {
    float: none;
}
.subnav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
}
.options:hover .subnav {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

h1{
    color: #E6E6FA;
    font-size:45px;
    font-family: Awesome;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px;
}
h2{
    color:white;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px;
}

.borda-direita{
   border-right: 1px solid #0000CD;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="settings">
        <a href="https://github.com/burnsecurity"><img src="https://designmodo.com/demo/dropdown-menu-search/settings.png" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="options">
        <a href="#">Serviços</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">PenTest</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="paginas/ferramentas.html">Ferramentas</a>
    </li>
<li class="options borda-direita">
  <a href="#">Cursos</a>
  <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="paginas/certificados.html">Premium</a></li>
      <li><a href="paginas/gratuitos.html">Gratuitos</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
    <li id="search">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search"/>
            <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button"></a>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li class="options">
        <a href="#">Tutoriais</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="paginas/hacking.html">Hacking</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/programacao.html">Programação</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/pentest.html">PenTest</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/outros.html">Outros</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="paginas/contato.html">Contato</a>
    <li class="borda-direita">
        <a href="paginas/sobre.html">Sobre</a>
    </li>
</ul> 
<center><h1>BurnSec</h1></center>
```